# Spring MVC validation - both validate REST submission and ad-hoc object creation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
public class Department {

    @NotNull
    public final List<String> employees;

    @JsonCreator
    public RoleViewWithUserIds(final @JsonProperty("employees") List<String> employees) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(employees, "employees");
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

And want to validate it with this MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public DepartmentView create(HttpServletRequest request,
                         @RequestBody @Valid Department submission,
                        BindingResult result) {

if (result.hasErrors()) {
    // 400 Bad Request
```

The idea is that enforce validity in two cases:

1. When the user submits a `Department` (using the `BindingResult`)
2. When the back end code constructs a `Department` object outside of the Spring MVC controller methods (using the constructor assertions)

Unfortunately, I can't see a way of enforcing both constraints in the same class. Is there a way of doing this or do I have to have two separate types?

---

EDIT: I'm now wondering if there is a way of doing the validation on a proxy object related to the submitted object type, so that the POJO itself can be created and validated like any other.

Answer (score 1):

1. When the call comes to the controller, the `Department` model will be validated by `@Valid` and the results would be stored in `bindingResult`.
2. In case you create the object somewhere else and want to validate the object as per `jsr310` annotations: this cannot be done automatically on object creation, however, the code creating it can manually validate it by something like this:

   ```
   import org.springframework.validation.SmartValidator;

   ...

   @Autowired
   SmartValidator validator;

   ...

   TestModel model = new TestModel();
   BindingResult br = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(model, "myModel");
   validator.validate(model, br);
   ```

The results of the validation will now be stored in `br`.

So, only way to do this using constructor assertion is to take the instance of `SmartValidator` as a parameter to the constructor and assert there.

Comment: + 1 Thanks @Saheb that certainly works. I was hope to find a way that allows objects to be created and validated on creation in a natural way.